# dell inspiron 15 3521 drivers for ubuntu 15.10 64-bit

Tags: drivers

i already did installed Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit.where did i get the dell inspiron-15 3521 drivers for Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit.

Comment: Which drivers do you need? What does not work?

Comment: i need dell inspiron-15 3521 drivers .version Ubuntu  15.10

Comment: Drivers for what? Graphics, sound, other hardware?

Comment: @K.Arun there are no 'specific' drivers for that machine for Linux.  What exactly on the machine is not working?  Wireless?  Graphics?  If you state specifically what's not working or such, that'd be great because we can point you in the right direction that way...

Comment: all drivers need .i new to use Ubuntu give some tips.

Comment: Ubuntu is not Windows. You do not need drivers for everything. If the system works OK, you DO NOT NEED DRIVERS.

Comment: Drivers in Linux are not the same as they are in Windows. For the most part, everything will automatically work. If something doesn't, then you have a question. If everything does work, then you don't have a valid question, even if it was about Windows.

Comment: i can't play music&videos.

Comment: How so? Do they not load, do they jitter/stutter? Do you not have sound? ___We can't help you unless you actually give details___

Comment: ask some plugin system.

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

After reading your comments, i think you need to install audio and video codecs, not drivers.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

When you are asked to accept the license for Microsoft fonts, do it by pressing Tab, Enter.